# Facebook debugger is caching meta data for an old IP address

Tags: facebook, debugging, caching, ip

When I try and scrape my URL, http://development.classroom.me.uk, with the Facebook debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, I get back information for an older version of the website on an IP address that is no longer hosting this site.

The original IP was 46.32.233.216, but the new IP is 212.67.215.188.

I have another website running on the new IP:

http://advert.classroom.me.uk

This website gets scraped without any issues, so this is not a firewall problem.

Facebook is caching the domain http://development.classroom.me.uk with the old IP, which is why the scraper is returning a 502 [bad gateway] response. It is retrieving out of date data, but unable to actually return the URL:

1. Go to http://development.classroom.me.uk, and view source.

In the document head, you will see:

<meta property="og:title" content="classroom" />
<meta property="og:description" content="classroom provides a digital communication platform for teachers and students" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://development.classroom.me.uk/images/logo/logo-facebook.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://development.classroom.me.uk" />

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, and type in http://development.classroom.me.uk into the input field. Press 'Debug'

I would expect to see information about the Facebook meta tags provided above.

I actually see data from an old version of this website held on an IP address that no longer hosts this site. In fact the old website contains no Facebook meta tags at all, which is why you can see data being scraped from the HTML title & standard meta description tag, instead...

Can anyone provide a solution for how I can clear the Facebook proxy cache. I have tried submitting this issue several times on Facebook, but no one from Facebook has provided me with a proper solution...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. With the help of the Facebook IT Department, we got to the bottom of this one. Indeed, the data was being cached. This was not a firewall issue, as I suspected, even though I was told repeatedly that it was.

I placed a new index page up at http://development.classroom.me.uk on my new IP 212.67.215.188

The page contained an HTML skeleton. See below [note, I placed no data in the document body]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="classroom, home, yoga, indian head massage, tai chi, feng shui, united kingdom, therapy" />
    <meta name="description" content="classroom provides a digital communication platform for teachers and students" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="classroom" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="classroom provides a digital communication platform for teachers and students" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />       
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://development.classroom.me.uk/images/logo/logo-facebook.png" />      
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://development.classroom.me.uk" />

    <title>classroom</title>

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>

</html>
```

I then used the Facebook debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to scrape this address again. Voila. The page returned a 200 response & the correct meta data.

The cache has been cleared.

Unfortunately, when I returned the correct index page back to http://development.classroom.me.uk, I still get a 502 response from the Facebook debugger. However, the important thing, is that the correct meta data & image remain.

I am going to try and work out why I am getting the 502 response, and when I do, I will let you know. I thought I would write up the answer now, as I know several developers have been troubled by this issue..